# x86-64 Assembly multiplication by 4

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I am trying to find an alternative to using imull and thus have a question that follows.

Would `sall $2, %eax` have the same effect on %eax as `leal 0(,%eax,4), %eax`, which should be multiplication by 4 to be exact?

Comment: Yes. For unsigned you can use shll too.

Comment: @dascandy that works for signed integers too

Comment: @dascandy: `shl` and `sal` are literally the same instruction, just alternate mnemonics for the same opcode.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SAL:SAR:SHL:SHR.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, `sall $2, %eax` multiplies `eax` by *four*, i.e., it shifts the bits of register `eax` *two* positions to the left.

Note that `sal` and `shl` are actually *synonyms*, whereas `sar` and `shr` are not. There is no distinction between *signed* and *unsigned* for the *left* shift.

In your case you are simply shifting the bits of the register to the *left*, signedness of the operand to be shifted does not matter, since the most significant bit (i.e., the sign bit) does not need to be interpreted as such as it is the case for the *right arithmetic shift*.